# permalink of word press in htacess

Tags: customization, permalinks

Hi I have used wp permalink and set custom category to /%category%/%postname%/ when it doesn't work I have used plugin too but it didn't work

[image]

can any one please help me to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any plugin to make it works. When you enabled Permalink, WordPress would automatically create a .htaccess file in your root directory, you need to make sure that the root directory is writable. Please take a look at this [article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/why-you-cant-find-htaccess-file-on-your-wordpress-site/) and see whether you can solve it.